# Check if specific data exist in a DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

Suppose I have 2 DataTables, DSALL and DSSome for storing student information

**DSALL** (Store all student information)

> SID (PK)
>   Name
>   Address
>   Telephone
>  ...

**DSSome** (Store only SID for some specific students)

> SID (Unique)

Now I want a C# function to check if all SID in DSSome exist in DSALL. The function return true if all SID exist in DSALL, return false if otherwise.

The traditional way is

```
protected bool checkSID(DataTable DSALL, DataTable DSSome){  
  for (int i=0; i<DSSome.Rows.Count; i++){
    bool isFound = false;
    string SID = DSSome.Rows[i]["SID"].ToString();
    for (int j=0; j<DSALL.Rows.Count; j++){
      string _SID = DSALL.Rows[j]["SID"].ToString();
      if (SID == _SID) { isFound = true; break; }
    }
    if (!isFound) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Is there any other simpler way of efficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: You could use [DataTable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) to replace the inner loop - `DataRow[] rows = DSALL.Select("SID=" + _SID); if (rows.Length >0) { isFound = true; }`.  LINQ might be more efficient to read, but I don't know if it would actually *be* more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another option. It grabs all SIDs from DSSOME, *except* those that occur in DSALL. If there are any values left-over in DSSOME that don't exist in DSALL, `.Any()` will return `true`.

Then you can just negate the value, since you wanted to return `true` if there *weren't* any left-over values in DSSOME.

```
return !DSSome.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(x => x["SID"])
              .Except(DSALL.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(x => x["SID"])).Any();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return DSSome.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
       .All(r => DSAll.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
       .Where(x => (string)x["SID"] == (string)r["SID"]).Count() == 1)
```

This is using a linq query to compare values from the two sets. The OfType<> is used to convert the Rows collection to `Rows<DataRow>` in order to use LINQ. All() will return true if all rows met the criteria. It returns false otherwise.

Comment: Adding an explanation of **what** the code is doing would be very helpful to future readers of this question.

Comment: Ok, I added an explanation